# Passing $options to form builder in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have this code in my form builder

```
->add('user', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'Acme\Entity\User',
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($options) {
                        return $er->createQueryBuilder('u') 
                        ->where('u.id = :id')
                        ->setParameter('id',$options['my'])
                        ->orderBy('u.name', 'ASC');},))
```

When I echo `$options['my']` I get output as `1` inside the builder.
Now when I submit the form, I get NULL as the User object.

But if I use  `->setParameter('id',1)` then it works fine.

Now if i use this

`$options['test'] = 1` inside the build form and use

`->setParameter('id',$options['test'])` then it also work fine.

But ->setParameter('id',$options['my']) is not working directly. It is echoing fine as 1 in the form , so value is in that variable.

What should I do?

Comment: For debugging Symfony2 application, I really like LadyBugBundle: https://github.com/raulfraile/LadybugBundle Hope it can help your future debugging ;) Best regards,
Christophe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a common error of type. `1` is a **string** in the first case and a **int** in the second case. Try if this works:

```
->setParameter('id',intval($options['my']))
```

Your debug is really good though, but it is better to use `var_dump` rather than `echo`. You can also compare the types with `gettype()`.

Compare `var_dump($options['my'])` with `var_dump($options[test'])`.

Compare `gettype($options['my'])` with `gettype($options['test'])`.